# How to delete all _version of a record in Amplify GraphQL when using Conflict Resolution

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, amplifyjs

i am a newer with Amplify AWS. My project is using Conflict Resolution with strategy Auto Merge, and using GraphQL.

[image]

When i call api mutation delete a record like this:

```
mutation DeleteEvents($input: DeleteEventsInput!, $condition: ModelEventsConditionInput) {
  deleteEvents(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
    id
    name
    location
    startDate
    endDate
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    _version
    _deleted
    _lastChangedAt
  }
}
```

Vars

```
{
  "input": {
    "id": "09bcc5a1-ff4f-40b5-93e0-e19534af7ff6",
    "_version": 1
  }
}
```

The api is success, but when I try to refetch the list, that record still on the list, with `_deleted` flag is true and `_version` increased 1.

```
{
  "listEvents": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "09bcc5a1-ff4f-40b5-93e0-e19534af7ff6",
        "name": "db223222",
        "_version": 2,
        "_deleted": true,
        "_lastChangedAt": 1684213601618
      }
    ],
    "nextToken": null,
    "startedAt": null
  }
}
```

Question is: How can i delete the record totally with all versions? Or I need filter _deleted in the query list?

Thank you very much!

I tried to remove `_version` in variables but the api would be failed

```
mutation DeleteEvents($input: DeleteEventsInput!, $condition: ModelEventsConditionInput) {
  deleteEvents(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
    id
    name
    location
    startDate
    endDate
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    _version
    _deleted
    _lastChangedAt
  }
}
```

Vars

```
{
  "input": {
    "id": "09bcc5a1-ff4f-40b5-93e0-e19534af7ff6"
  }
}
```

Error: Conflict resolver rejects mutation because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390956/when-to-disable-aws-amplify-or-appsync-conflict-resolution)